# ¿Qué significa la letra r precediendo una constante de cadena?

Tags: python

Me he topado con una constante de cadena de caracteres que está precedida por una letra `r`, de la siguiente forma:

```
a_expresion = r"\[(.*?)\]"
```

No había visto esto antes y me pregunto

- ¿qué significa la `r` precediendo la cadena?
- ¿qué varía entre `'cadena'` y `r'cadena'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las constantes de cadena pueden precederse de una `r` que significa **raw** (en inglés); algo así como *cruda* o ***literal*** en español.

Una *constante literal de cadena*, como la llamaré, tiene una sintaxis ligeramente diferente que una constante de cadena *normal*. en la cual el caracter *diagonal inversa* `\` no tiene ningún significado especial, en otras palabras, no es el inicio de una secuencia de escape, sino que se toma su valor literal. En una *constante literal de cadena*, `\n` es exactamente eso, `\n` y no `CRLF` o <kbd>enter</kbd>, `\t` no es tab, etc.

Hasta donde sé, la única excepción a esta regla es cuando la diagonal inversa se encuentra antes de la comilla, que de otra forma terminaría la cadena.

Esto evita tener que poner dobles diagonales inversas para evitar iniciar secuencias de escape, como habría que hacer en una constante de cadena *normal*.

Esta variante resulta muy conveniente cuando se escriben constantes que representan:

- Expresiones regulares
- Rutas de archivos (en Windows)
- Y otras que suelen contener frecuentemente el caracter literal `\`

Que no solo son más fáciles de escribir, sino se ven *menos cargadas*, lo que facilita su inspección y depuración.

Comparemos algunos ejemplos, en ambas variantes:

```
patron_simple = r"\[(.*?)\]"
patron_simple2 = "\\[(.*?)\\]"

patron_url = r"^(http|https|ftp):[\/]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~]*)"
patron_url2 = "^(http|https|ftp):[\\/]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?\\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\._\\?\\,\\'\\/\\\\\\+&amp;%\\$#\\=~]*)"

narchivo = r"c:\users\jachguate\documents\a\b\c\d\e\documento.doc"
narchivo2 = "c:\\users\\jachguate\\documents\\a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\documento.doc"
```

La expresión de tu pregunta, dado que no tiene más que un par de caracteres, no resulta tan *pesada* en su forma *normal*, pero las siguientes creo que dejan más que clara la conveniencia de escribirlas de manera *literal*.

Sobre tu pregunta final, entre `'cadena'` y `r'cadena'` no hay ninguna variación, pues no contiene ningún caracter `\`, en cambio, esto si que varía:

```
c1 =  "hola\n¿como estás?"
c2 = r"hola\n¿como estás?"
print(c1)
print(c2)
```

la salida es:

```
hola
¿como estás?
hola\n¿como estás?
```