# Error al enviar imagen por WhatsApp

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

Estoy intentando enviar una imagen por WhatsApp con Python y Selenium.

Código:

```
driver_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options = options)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
contacto = "1100001111" #telefono
mgs = "Prueba desde WhatBot"
#ruta de imagen
imagen = "C:\pt-Python\scrap\WhatBot\banner.png"

WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]")))\
    .send_keys(imagen)
```

El proceso lo hace bien, ingresa a WhatsApp, busca al usuario a través de su número de teléfono y envía el mensaje, pero cuando quiero enviar una imagen no me sale este error.

#Error

> imagen = "C:\pt-Python\scrap\WhatBot\banner.png"
> ^
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncated \xXX escape
> [Finished in 0.2s]

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Lee esto, te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/442489/21

Comment: Ok, voy a leerlo, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imagen = "C:\pt-Python\scrap\WhatBot\banner.png"
```

Al usar `\` en un string, Python lo interpreta como un caracter de escape si va seguido de ciertas letras. Para evitarlo, puedes escribir `\\`. [Más información](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp).

En concreto, el error está en que en la dirección aparece `\b`, que es el caracter de escape correspondiente al retroceso (backspace).

**Soluciones**:

Opción recomendada:

```
imagen = "C:/pt-Python/scrap/WhatBot/banner.png"
```

O bien:

```
imagen = "C:\\pt-Python\\scrap\\WhatBot\\banner.png"
```

Un poco más corto:

```
imagen = "C:\pt-Python\scrap\WhatBot\\banner.png"
```

Para que te envíe la imagen:

```
from PIL import Image

driver_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options = options)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
contacto = "1100001111" #telefono
mgs = "Prueba desde WhatBot"
#ruta de imagen
imagen = "C:\\pt-Python\\scrap\\WhatBot\\banner.png"
im = Image.open(imagen)

WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]")))\
    .send_keys(im)
```

Comment: Gracias Angel. Los en dos casos me dieron errores: con el primer ejemplo 1imagen = "C:/pt-Python/scrap/WhatBot/banner.png"` Error 1 `- WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ` y con el segundo ejemplo `imagen = "C:\\pt-Python\\scrap\\WhatBot\\banner.png"` Error 2 `- 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: Comprendo lo que me dices, pero utilizo el primer ejemplo `imagen = "C:\\pt-Python\\scrap\\WhatBot\\banner.png"` y digamos que funciona, llega al usuario pero no envía la imagen, no sé si me esta faltando algo, pero lo bueno es que llega al usuario

Comment: Bueno, hice algunas correcciones, pero lo que hace ahora es enviar un texto. Envía `C:\\pt-Python\\scrap\\WhatBot\\banner.png` y no la imagen... jajajajaja

Comment: Me alegro de que se vaya solucionando. Envía el texto porque es lo que hay en la variable imagen. He incluido en la respuesta cómo hacer que envíe la imagen.

Comment: Muchas gracias Ángel por tu tiempo. La imagen no sube, pero de seguro algo estoy haciendo mal. Esto voy a tener que hacer tranquilo y paso a paso. Al menos ya hay  un problema menos...