# Python Tkinter: "icon.ico" not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy intentando agregarle un icono a una ventana pero no me deja, simplemente me tira de error

```
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "ddbb.ico" not defined
```

Y no tengo idea de porque, les dejo el codigo.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox *

root=Tk()
root.title("Gestor de BBDD")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.iconbitmap("ddbb.ico")

root.mainloop()
```

Cabe aclarar que la imagen de extensión .ico la tengo en el mismo directorio en el que está el archivo .py, asi que debería funcionar.

Por cierto, ya intente poner el path completo y tampoco funcionó. Todo esto lo hago desde una pc virtual con Lubuntu, no sé si .ico funcione en linux pero busque en internet y no decía nada al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución sería la siguiente

```
icono="base64" # Es un ejemplo de la imagen en base 64

icondata = base64.b64decode(icono)
tempfile="icon.ico"
iconfile=open(tempfile,"wb")
iconfile.write(icondata)
iconfile.close()

root.iconbitmap("ddbb.ico") # Este es tu código
root.wm_iconbitmap(tempfile)
```

Está puede ser otra posible solución, para que reconozca el icono.

Answer (score 0):

`_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "ddbb.ico" not defined`

Es el error que tkinter proporciona al usuario cuando la imagen no se ha encontrado.

Aunque el archivo esté en la misma carpeta, muchas veces tkinter lanza el error. Una solución sería usar una [Raw String](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442488/qu%C3%A9-significa-la-letra-r-precediendo-una-constante-de-cadena).

## Código

```py
root.iconbitmap(r'carpeta_del_archivo\ddub.ico')
```

Answer (score 0):

No me reconoció el icono de la primer forma, pero prueba con la siguiente línea:

1. ```
   root.iconbitmap=('python.ico') #Para colocar nuestro icono
   ```
2. ```
   root.wm_iconbitmap("python.ico") #otra forma de colocar el icono
   ```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la "primera forma"?

Answer (score 0):

El formato .ico es especifico de Windows, en Linux puedes usar `iconphoto`/`wm_iconphoto`.

El primer parámetro es una bandera boolean, que de definirse como `True` hace que el icono sea heredado también por las ventanas hijas. Puedes pasarle múltiples imágenes al método, con distintos tamaños (16x16, 32x32, 64x64, etc) para dar distintas opciones al gestor de ventanas si necesita usar iconos de distintos tamaños. Debe funcionar también en Windows y Mac.

`tkinter.PhotoImage` acepta GIF, PGM, PPM, y PNG. Se pueden usar otros formatos a través de Pillow.

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Gestor de BBDD")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(0,0)

icon = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, file='ddub.png')
root.wm_iconphoto(True, icon)

root.mainloop()
```